# The argument type 'BoxShadow' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<BoxShadow>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to build a custom list Item in flutter. When I am trying to assign box radius to the list item I am facing the below syntax error:

```
**The argument type 'BoxShadow' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<BoxShadow>'.**
```

It seems like I couldn't assign box shadow to the list. I am new to flutter is there a way to add custom box shadow to a list item of an AnimatedList(). I have provided the code below:

```
Widget _buildItem(UserModel user, [int index]) {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey[50],
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
    boxShadow: BoxShadow(
      blurRadius: 5.0
    )
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      InkWell(
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 30.0,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photo, scale: 64.0),
        ),
        onLongPress: index != null ? () => deleteUser(index) : null,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `boxShadow` must contain list [],

Your fix is,

```
...
         boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.amber.shade100,
                    blurRadius: 15.0,
                    // has the effect of softening the shadow
//                    spreadRadius: 2.0,
                    // has the effect of extending the shadow
                    offset: Offset(
                      1.0, // horizontal, move right 10
                      5.0, // vertical, move down 10
                    ),
                  )
                ],
```

Comment: Sure. Will make it as accepted answer too in a moment.